# High CPU load on LibreOffice menu

Tags: libreoffice, gnome-classic, cpu

My Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with gnome-classic shows a large CPU usage after I highlight any LibreOffice app in gnome menu (Apps->Office-> *).. only on LibreOffice.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Libre Office is quite some ressource intensive. 
If you want a light system I recommend the office software Lubuntu uses: Spreadsheet, Wordprocessor, Notes and maybe planning calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Libreoffice settings and change Memory > Undo > Number of Steps to 10...  Also change View > Graphics output > Turn ON Use hardware Acceleration, Turn OFF Use Antialiasing (looks jaggy but speeds up page drawing)...  Hope this helps a little...

Also, turning OFF automatic spell-checking and grammar checking will improve performance...

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I am thinking just about gnome-panel - it slows down before launching LibreOffice.